# How can I have wolfram alpha perform substitutions?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I've used Wolfram Alpha for years, but I've never really understood how to type in complex formulas so that Wolfram Alpha can understand them.

Specifically, I struggle with telling Wolfram Alpha what certain variables stand for.

For example, I want to perform a sum of three numbers: `x_1=3`, `x_2=4`, and `x_3=1`.

But, when I type `x_1 = 3, x_2 = 4, x_3 = 1, compute sum from i = 1 to 3 of x_i`, which Wolfram Alpha correctly interprets as

[image: Correct interpretation by Wolfram Alpha]

I get the wonderful result

[image: Failed Wolfram Alpha interpretation]

(What I was looking for was `3+4+1=8`)

In other words, Wolfram Alpha understands my question and the information, but doesn't actually carry out the substitution to give me the answer I want.

Is there any way to force Wolfram Alpha to put in the substitution?